# JDEE runs maven all the time

Tags: java

I am opening a Java source file which is part of a maven project. JDEE now runs maven once, which I can sort of understand. But whenever I move around in the file, it will trigger once more. Since it always splits my frame, and blocks Emacs, this is quite annoying.

Is there a how to or some rules on how to set up Emacs and JDEE for my Maven projects, so that this will not happen?

Comment: I agree! This is really annoying...

Comment: I did `(jdee-maven-disabled-p t)` to stop maven execution. Probably it is not my time for Java on Emacs... Who knows in the future...

Answer (score 0):

The maven compile buffer only happens when you open the project the first time, try with `mvn dependency:build-classpath -Dclassifier=sources` to check is successful getting all the sources otherwise that will be the reason that why always run maven buffer on the startup